# ¿Cómo reorganizar una pila?

Tags: java

tengo reorganizar una pila los pongo en contexto de lo que requiere hacer

Se define PILA REORGANIZABLE como aquella en la que, a la hora de insertar un número n,
Si n ya se encuentra en la pila, n es desplazado a la cima,
conservando el resto de elementos su orden relativo.
Si n no se encuentra en la pila, n es apilado en la cima

tengo el siguiente metodo pero me hace falta cosas xd, me pueden dar alguna idea de como puedo solucionarlo  gracias de ante mano

```
// clase nodoPila
public class NodoPila {
    
    private int informacion;
    private NodoPila siguiente;

    public NodoPila() {
    }
public NodoPila(int informacion, NodoPila siguiente) {
        this.informacion = informacion;
        this.siguiente = siguiente;
    }
    //metodos getters y setters .... no los pongo para no hacer tan largo esto
}


//clase Pila
public class Pila(){

  NodoPila ultimoValorIngresado;


 public boolean buscar(int dato) {
        NodoPila aux = ultimoValorIngresado;
        boolean existe = false;

        while (existe != true && aux != null) {
            if (dato == aux.getInformacion()) {
                existe = true;
            } else {
                aux = aux.getSiguiente();
            }
        }
        return existe;
    }

    public void reorganizable(Pila p, int nodo) {
        boolean exisite = buscar(nodo);
        if (!p.pilaVacia()) {
            System.out.println("la pila no esta vacia ");
            if (exisite) {
                System.out.println("el dato existe, desapilando...");
                nodo = p.desapilar();
            } else {
                System.out.println("el dato no existe, apilando ...");
                p.Apilar(nodo);
            }
            p.Apilar(p.desapilar());

        }
    }
  
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Pila p = new Pila();
        
        p.Apilar(1);
        p.Apilar(2);
        p.Apilar(3);
        
  

        System.out.println("organizabble");
        p.reorganizable(p, 3);
        p.mostrarPila();
        
     
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar las demás clases que estás utilizando?

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza men solo la clase nodoPila con dos atributos y la clase pila , edite la publicacion xd

Answer (score 1):

Usa una función recursiva cuya entrada sea la pila y el valor a buscar, que vaya desapilando todos los elementos, hasta llegar al fondo o al elemento buscado.

Si se encuentra con el fondo de la pila, que reapile todos los valores, y la ultima llamada apile el valor buscado. En caso de no llegar al fondo, no apile de nuevo el valor encontrado, y todas las llamadas anteriores apilen sus valores. Al final, de nuevo, que se apile el valor buscado.

Pseudo-código:

```
stack ordena_pila(stack s, value v)
{
  ordena_pila_r(s, v);
  s.push(v);
}

stack ordena_pila_r(stack s, value v)
{
  if(!s.void()) {
    value t = s.pop();
    ordena_pila_r(s, v);
    if(v != t)
      s.push(t);
  }
}
```

Comment: si lo se amigo, pero primero tengo que hacer uno normal sin recursividad el de recursividad ya lo tengo hecho

Comment: Pues simplemente usa tu estructura de pila con bucles para simular la pila de llamadas. Teniendo ya la estructura de pila, es simplemente partir el cuerpo de ordena_pila_r en uno o dos while...